# Whence the horizontal shift in pure-CSS parallax?

Tags: css, parallax

I'm trying to produce a pure-CSS parallax effect following the approach from [this post](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/). It mostly works; however, there are some artifacts when the parallaxed elements are not full-width.

In the snippet below, the `hero` element (with specified dimensions) is meant to scroll more slowly than the rest of the page. The container's `perspective-origin` points exactly to the middle of the hero element, so applying `transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);` to the hero should not move it at all. But it does produce a horizontal shift of a few pixels. (Vertical position is fine.)

Why does this happen, and how to fix it?

```css
.container { 
  height: 500px; 
  background: #eee; 
  overflow-y: auto; 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  perspective: 1px; 
  perspective-origin: 50% 171.5px; 
}

.hero { 
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1256x343'); 
  height: 343px; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2); 
  max-width: 1256px; 
}

.main { 
  background: rebeccapurple; 
  height: 2000px; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  max-width: 1256px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero"></div>
  <div class="main">Scroll me down</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks fine to me (no horizontal movement at all) in Chrome 64 & Firefox 56.

Answer (score 0):

This layout is based on the hero element being perfectly centered on the container.

Then, perspective-origin-x: 50% will work ....

But, as long as you have a scroll bar on the right side, the content-box size is no longer the same in container and hero, and it misses the alignment.

Take a look at [this post](https://codepen.io/GabbeV/post/problems-with-pure-css-parallax) for more details and a solution that may be could work in your case

```
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
#wrapper1{
  width: calc(100% + 17px);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#wrapper2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1px;
  perspective-origin: calc(100% - 17px) center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#wrapper3{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.parallax_layer1{
  transform-origin: 100% center;
  transform: translateZ(-.4px) scale(1.4); /* scale=1-translateZ/perspective */
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
section{
  background: #111;
  height: 50vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  width: 100%;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: -5vh 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```